# Passing Data Between Activities in Android App

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Hey I am pretty new to making android apps and I understand that the easiest way to pass data between two activities is through an intent.

In one of my classes (EventOptions.java), I call this line of code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(EventOptions.this, PhotoFetcher.class);
i.putExtra("imageArray", imageIDs); 
startActivity(i);
```

imageIDs is a string array

In my PhotoFetcher class, I want to set a string array called imageIDs to the imageIDs string array that I am passing through the intent.

I want to set images as a global variable in my class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Intent it = getIntent();
    String[] imageIDs = it.getStringArrayExtra("imageArray");
    ...
}
```

This crashes my app however. Is this not allowed? And if so, how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by crashing your app? What's the error message. There's a method putStringArrayListExtra by the way which might suit your needs

Comment: please add your crash logs .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to call `getIntent()` in a method instead of at class level. call it inside `onCreate` :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // get Intent here
    Intent it = getIntent();
    String[] imageIDs = it.getStringArrayExtra("imageArray");
}
```

> if I want to use the imageIDs array in another public class defined
>   in my PhotoFetcher class, do I need to call it again?

To get `imageIDs`in `PhotoFetcher` class  either declare String[] `imageIDs` as global variable or pass `imageIDs` using `PhotoFetcher` class constructor

Comment: That's what I am doing right now but if I want to use the imageIDs array in another public class defined in my PhotoFetcher class, do I need to call it again? Is there no way I can set it as a global variable?

Comment: Ah okay this makes sense. I ended up passing it in as a parameter to my inner class. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `putStringArrayListExtra`. You can convert your String[] to an ArrayList first.

Like so

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(imageIDs));
Intent i = new Intent(EventOptions.this, PhotoFetcher.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra("imageArray", arrayList); 
startActivity(i);
```

And then you can fetch it like you do, preferably in `onCreate` or after that call.

```
Intent it = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> imageIDs = it.getStringArrayListExtra("imageArray");
```

Comment: I am passing in a string array not a list ]=

Comment: Naturally, you will have to convert it first. See my updated answer. @DavidYuan

Answer (score 0):

**Share data without persisting to disk**

It is possible to share data between activities by saving it in memory given that, in most cases, both activities run in the same process.

Note: sometimes, when the user leaves your activity (without quitting it), Android may decide to kill your application. In such scenario, I have experienced cases in which android attempts to launch the last activity using the intent provided before the app was killed. In this cases, data stored in a singleton (either yours or Application) will be gone and bad things could happen. To avoid such cases, you either persist objects to disk or check data before using it to make sure its valid.

**Use a singleton class**

Have a class to whole the data:

```
public class DataHolder {
  private String data;
  public String getData() {return data;}
  public void setData(String data) {this.data = data;}

  private static final DataHolder holder = new DataHolder();
  public static DataHolder getInstance() {return holder;}
}
From the launched activity:

String data = DataHolder.getInstance().getData();
```

**Use application singleton (I would recommend this)**

The application singleton is an instance of android.app.Application which is created when the app is launched. You can provide a custom one by extending Application:

```
import android.app.Application;
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  private String data;
  public String getData() {return data;}
  public void setData(String data) {this.data = data;}
}
```

Before launching the activity:

```
MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
app.setData(someData);
```

Then, from the launched activity:

```
MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
String data = app.getData();
```

Comment: Ah okay this was a good read. Never thought about storing data this way. Thanks a lot! I will definitely look into this method in the future. I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

ρяσѕρєя K hit the nail on the head, you're running a method where constructors and fields go.  To make the variables (the imageIDs) global, it's quite simple and there are a few ways of doing it.  Declare them outside any method, and then assign them in your onCreate or onResume (which will always be called).

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
 //global variable
String[] imageIDs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // get Intent here
        Intent it = getIntent();
        imageIDs = it.getStringArrayExtra("imageArray");
    }

}
```